# How will brexit affect the British export and import?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, economy, brexit, trade

Will there be any positive consequences that are expected from Brexit or is it mainly expected to be bad for the British trade?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange as I see this is your first post. I’ll spare you a downvote since it is your first time and I’m exchange give you some advice. One, I would never say this you are asking for homework. Two, you’re question is way broad. Three, I’m sure there are dozens of questions about brexits affec On the UK, so I would search for those. I do hope you continue to use this platform because it’s a very useful place to learn.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bexit hasn't entered in action yet.

Comment: This is an economics question really

Answer (score 2):

If the question is "... has affected ..." and not "... will affect ..." you will have to look into the effects of **uncertainty**.

- Google about companies in a just-in-time transport loop which are stockpiling more supplies, if they can.
- Google about decisions being postponed.
- Google about companies (banks, airlines) opening EU-based headquarters in addition to their UK-based offices.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons, what link? Here I was trying to help a kid get started with the homework, without doing the homework for him or her.

Comment: It's the default review queue message - I felt that 'link only' was appropriate for 'google this' answers.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons, OK. The question is on hold anyway. In History SE I've given "read this, read that"-style answers to homework questions before ...